# Can someone help identifying these trim profiles?

Tags: carpentry

I’m wondering if someone can help me identify these trim profiles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the top one looks like a combination of multiple profiles

Answer (score 1):

Curved edge architrave comes in several basic types - chamfered & bullnose don't interest us here, so we're looking for 'ogee', which is an S shape, 'torus', a half round & 'ovalo' which is a quarter round.

Ogee, torus, ovalo
[image]

After that, everything else is a compound.

Your skirting is an ogee, but it has a slightly uncharacteristic top edge, which appears to be rounded. It also has a very unusual shallow groove below the S.
'Standard' ogee tends to have a chamfered top edge, sometimes that chamfer is slightly smoothed/rounded, but I have never seen one with a completely rounded top.

[image]

Your door architrave is far more complex. It looks like it starts on the right with a regular torus, but then it looks like two different sized dowels have been used. It may all be one piece, you can get some quite complex compounds, but they tend to have either manufacturer's 'made up' names, or just design numbers.

Sometimes, they are made up of simpler components, which look more complex in situ.
My own archetraves at home are made of 4 components, almost masquerading as one.  Square trim makes the door close, bullnose goes out to the actual underlying door-frame, which after a gap is then trimmed in regular ogee.
<sub>'scuse the fine art illustrations ;)</sub>

[image]

There are companies that specialise in 'victorian' architrave of varying complexities, and even some that will copy an existing design.
Here are some UK examples:-
https://www.thevictorianemporium.com/store/category/architrave
https://www.periodmouldings.co.uk/c/architraves/victorian-architraves/
https://www.skirtingexpress.co.uk/architrave-1/

Comment: TL;DR: "Built up on site". I think that's the only proper answer here. +1

Answer (score 0):

You only show one profile, and it's an [**ogee**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogee)

Comment: Just added the second image